# for loop is executed always just ONCE

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Brief information image, what my code do:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
private void CheckObjectAttackPoints(Point AttackPoint){
    Point ObjectAttackPoint = AttackPoint;
    ObjectAttackPoint.X -= 1;
    int count=0; //This variable for reading how many tiles are false
    //Check tiles active and ObjectAttackPoint is exist in List
    for (int i=0; i < 1;i++) {
        if (GameManager.AllPoints.Contains (ObjectAttackPoint)) {
            if (!GameManager.TileColliders [ObjectAttackPoint.X, ObjectAttackPoint.Y].activeSelf) {
                count++;
                ObjectAttackPoints [i] = ObjectAttackPoint;
                Debug.Log (ObjectAttackPoints [i].X +", " + ObjectAttackPoints [i].Y);
            }
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            break;
        }
        ObjectAttackPoint.X += 2;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        Debug.Log ("Object can attack " + count + " points");
    }

}
```

So, this method need `AttackPoint` which already has `AttackPoint.Y-1` value, we need only to check if `AttackPoint.X` exists in `List` and check if object at this point is active. At the method start, `AttackPoint.X` decreases its value by 1.

My problem is that console returns only one point even if two tiles are not active (Example image: 0,0 and 0,2 tiles are not active, console returns only count=1 and tile with Point 0,0), this means that method checks only one tile and my code have a mistake, but I can't understand where it is.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Yes, because the `i < 1` condition won't allow the for loop to execute more than once...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is executed always exactly just ONCE, your method's code is equivalent to this:

```cs
private void CheckObjectAttackPoints(Point AttackPoint) {
    Point ObjectAttackPoint = AttackPoint;
    ObjectAttackPoint.X -= 1;
    int count = 0; //This variable for reading how many tiles are false
                   //Check tiles active and ObjectAttackPoint is exist in List
    if (GameManager.AllPoints.Contains(ObjectAttackPoint)) {
        if (!GameManager.TileColliders[ObjectAttackPoint.X, ObjectAttackPoint.Y].activeSelf) {
            count++;
            ObjectAttackPoints[0] = ObjectAttackPoint;
            Debug.Log(ObjectAttackPoints[0].X + ", " + ObjectAttackPoints[0].Y);
        }
    }
    ObjectAttackPoint.X += 2;

    if (count > 0) {
        Debug.Log("Object can attack " + count + " points");
    }
}
```

If you want to cycle through all elements of `ObjectAttackPoint`, you should use

If it's a `List`:

```cs
for (int i=0; i < ObjectAttackPoint.Count;i++)
```

If it's an `array`:

```cs
for (int i=0; i < ObjectAttackPoint.Length;i++)
```

**EDIT**: what's the use of the `break` condition when `i==1` anyway? Even if you extend the for loop, that `if` will break the loop exactly after two loops (i.e. after it's executed for `i == 0` and `i == 1`). You should explain more in depth what's `ObjectAttackPoints`.

Comment: I missed slightest mistake again ._. Instruction i==1 just for break loop, i need only 2 array values (points), therefore my loop property is (int i=0; i<=1; i++)

Comment: Then you don't need at all the `if(i==1) break;` condition, you just need to loop twice with `for (int i=0; i <= 1;i++) {}`

Comment: Oh, okay, break condition was just for test in this method, thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
There are a few problems with this code:

1. The `i < 1` condition won't allow the for loop to execute more than once.
2. This code can be considered as a fairly good example of 'spaghetti code', it's considered a bad practice to use `break` operator in a loop unless it's absolutely necessary.
3. There is no need to use a for loop to perform a limited number of operations that are known in advance
4. Check for each attack point could be and imho *should be* done in a separate method.

You can do something along the lines of:

```
private bool CheckObjectAttackPoint(Point AttackTo)
{
   return GameManager.AllPoints.Contains(AttackTo) && !GameManager.TileColliders[AttackTo.X, AttackTo.Y].activeSelf
}

private bool CheckObjectAttackPoint(Point AttackFrom, int xDiff, yDiff)
{
   var pointToAttack = new Point(AttackFrom.X + xDiff, AttackFrom.Y + yDiff);
   return CheckObjectAttackPoint(pointToAttack);
}
```

Now you can use this method by providing it with attack points:

```
Point objCurrentPoint = ...; // Currect position is (1;1)
CheckObjectAttackPoint(objCurrentPoint, -1, -1);
CheckObjectAttackPoint(objCurrentPoint, +1, -1);
```

Comment: I'm trying to organize my code and my experience is low for understand how to find the best way, but i keep practise, so thanks for this description

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the cycle definition:

> for (int i=0; i < 1;i++)

This means the code will be executed only once, for i=0. You could fix it like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<=1;i++)
```